# Element undefined in coldfusion.xml.XmlNodeMap

Tags: xml, coldfusion, rss, coldfusion-8

I am trying to load these RSS feeds from the NY Times:

- http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Business.xml
- http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Politics.xml

When I use the following line of code, everything loads fine, no errors.

```
     <a href="#XMLContent.rss.channel.item[idx].link.xmlText#">
        #XMLContent.rss.channel.i‌​tem[idx].title.xmlText#
     </a>
```

BUT when I actually click on the links, the URLs did not come over. I had a look at the `<cfdump>` and saw that for these feeds, the URLs are held in the **ID** and **rsslink** fields.  When I pull the feed, using either of one of these:

```
    <a href="#XMLContent.rss.channel.item[idx].id.xmlText#">
         #XMLContent.rss.channel.ite‌m[idx].title.xmlText#
    </a>
    <a href="#XMLContent.rss.channel.item[idx].rsslink.xmlText#">
        #XMLContent.rss.channe‌l.item[idx].title.xmlText#
    </a>
```

I get one of these errors:

> Element RSSLINK.XMLTEXT is undefined in a Java object of type class
>   coldfusion.xml.XmlNodeMap referenced as ''
>
> Element RSSLINK.XMLTEXT is undefined in a Java object of type class
>   coldfusion.xml.XmlNodeMap referenced as ''

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error? I have googled but to no avail.

Comment: when you dump out `XMLContent.rss.channel.item[idx]` what do you get?

Comment: @MattBusche - For the start of the first item it looks like this `<item><atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" href="http://dealbook.nytimes.com/2013/05/08/ing-plans-i-p-o-of-european-insurance-unit/?partner=rss&amp;emc=rss" rel="standout"/><title>DealBook: ING Plans I.P.O. of European Insurance Unit</title><link>http://dealbook.nytimes.com/2013/05/08/ing-plans-i-p-o-of-european-insurance-unit/?partner=rss&amp;emc=rss</link>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure where you getting "ID" and "rsslink". From what I can see, the "link" url is stored in an attribute named "href". Try using XmlAttributes:

```
#XMLContent.rss.channel.item[idx].link.XmlAttributes['href']#
```

**Update:**

I ran a few tests under CF8, and using the attribute worked fine (see below).  Note, you did not include the code you are using to parse the feed, so I guessed you are using `cffhtp` in combination with `xmlParse`.

```
<cfhttp url="http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Politics.xml" result="rssXML">
<cfset XMLContent = xmlParse(rssXML.fileContent)>

<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(XMLContent.rss.channel.item)#" index="idx">
    <cfset itemNode = XMLContent.rss.channel.item[idx]>
    <cfoutput>
        <a href="#itemNode.link.XmlAttributes['href']#">
            #itemNode.title.xmlText#
        </a><br />
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Note: The xml structure on the business feed seems to vary. Some of the nodes store the url in the `href` attribute and others in `link.xmlText`. XMLAttributes is a structure. So you can always use the structKeyExists function to verify the href attribute exists before using it. Then do something else if it is not found.

```
    <cfif structKeyExists(itemNode.link.XmlAttributes, "href")>
        attributes exists. go ahead and use it
    <cfelse>
        not found. do something else ...
    </cfif>
```

Comment: Hi @leigh - using that I get the error `Element href is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.xml.XmlAttrMap`

I run so many different feeds and have never had any errors like this - it really is puzzling. :(

Comment: I tested it with CF8 and it works fine. See updated response.

Comment: Oh my gosh - then that is the problem because I am trying to use the same code across the feeds (there are a stack of others) - and with the Business feed and like with  this news feed http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml <- I am getting the same issue. SO I need to cover both structures to get this to work?! Why would the NYTimes do this to their feeds?! GAH!!!

Comment: There are different types of feeds and different versions (see [the docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_f_01.html) for more info). You should check the feed version and verify you are handling it accordingly.

Comment: Wow - knock me down - I have it all working PERFECTLY! @Leigh - thank you so much and thank you for putting up with my bad mood today! I really appreciate all of your help - thank you for all the help you have given. You are a wonderful asset to these boards.